# Why isn't there an $x$ such that $\tan\left(\frac{\sin^{-1} x}{5}\right)=1$?

Tags: trigonometry

If $\tan\left(\frac{\sin^{-1} x}{5}\right)=1$, then $x$ is equal to

$$\frac{-\pi}{2}\le \sin^{-1}x \le \frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$\frac{-\pi}{10}\le \frac{\sin^{-1}x}{5} \le \frac{\pi}{10}$$

This show that no value of such $x$ exist.
I want to know why this is happening.

Now in this approach,
$$\frac{\sin^{-1}x}{5}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
$$\sin^{-1}x=\frac{5\pi}{4}$$
Why this is happening?

I think this is just happening because of principal value  of $\sin^{-1}x$.

Comment: By $\sin^{-1}(x)$ do you mean $\arcsin(x)$?

Comment: @Lovsovs Yes${}{}{}$

Comment: In what way can "why is this happening" be separated from the proof of it happening? The proof kind of explains the "why". arcsin(x) is bounded within a range which doesn't include the solution to tan(y/5)=1

Comment: @AakashKumar I think some of our edits may have clashed, sorry about that. Feel free to edit now (I won't be doing any more edits!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the range for $\arcsin(x)$ is $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, so no real $x$ satisfies $\arcsin(x)=\frac{5}{4}\pi$.

Comment: Good enough. I was checking with WA, and then I saw your answer.

Answer (score -1):

$\sin^{-1} x = \frac{5 \pi}{4}$ gives $x=\sin \frac{5 \pi}{4} = \sin (\pi + \frac{\pi}{4})$, then $x = -\sin \frac{\pi}{4} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$. Your error is restricting $\sin^{-1} x$ to the values $-\frac{\pi}{2} \le \sin^{-1} x \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ (the principal value is within this range).

Comment: Clearly that $x$ does not yield $1$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan(arcsin(-1%2Fsqrt(2))%2F5)

Comment: @Lovsovs isn't that because when Wolfram calculates $\sin^{-1} (\frac{-1}{\sqrt 2})$ it returns the value in the principle range?

Comment: Maybe, but still: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan(arcsin(x)%2F5)%3D1

Comment: Again, Wolfram is presumably just using the principle values of $\sin^{-1} x$. I'm just arguing that there is some value of $x$ for which $\sin^{-1} x = \frac{5 \pi}{4}$

Comment: How could there be? That is the same as saying, for instance, that there exists an $x$ s.t. $\cos(x)=2$ - it isn't in the range of $\cos(x)$.

Comment: Oh, doesn't $x = \sin \frac{5\pi}{4}$ solve this? I thought $\sin$ was a multivalued function.